# PostgreSQL Select Join Not in List

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The project is using Postgres 9.3

I have tables (that I have simplified) as follows:

```
t_person (30 million records)
- id
- first_name
- last_name
- gender

t_city (70,000 records)
- id
- name
- country_id

t_country (20 records)
- id
- name

t_last_city_visited (over 200 million records)
- person_id
- city_id
- country_id
  - There is a unique constraint on person_id, country_id to
    ensure that each person only has one last city per country
```

What I need to do are variations on the following:

**Get the ids of Person who are female who have visited country 'UK'
  but have never visited country 'USA'**

I have tried the following, but it is too slow.

```
select t_person.id from t_person
join t_last_city_visited
  on (
          t_last_city_visited.person_id = t_person.id
          and country_id = (select id from t_country where name = 'UK')
     )
where gender = 'female'
except
(
    select t_person.id from t_person
    join t_last_city_visited
      on (
             t_last_city_visited.person_id = t_person.id
             and country_id = (select id from t_country where name = 'USA')
         )
)
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You haven't mentioned exactly how slow. what additional indexes do all these tables have?

Comment: As Dmitry say. You have to provide the analyse result of your query. And tell us how much time take.

Comment: To all that responded - thank you.  There are indexes on all ID field (as they are foreign keys).  The (select id where name=x) can (in the code) be done ahead of time to not affect the query, so it is just a query of id lookups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What you want to do here is to find the females for whom there EXISTS a visit to the UK, but where NOT EXISTS a visit to the US.

Something like:

```
select ...
from   t_person
where  ...
   and exists (select null
                 from t_last_city_visited join
                      t_country on (...)
                where t_country.name = 'UK')
   and not exists (select null
                 from t_last_city_visited join
                      t_country on (...)
                where t_country.name = 'US')
```

Another approach, to find the people who have visited the UK and not the US, which you can then join to the people to filter by gender:

```
select   person_id
  from   t_last_city_visited join
         t_country on t_last_city_visited.country_id = t_country.id
 where   t_country.name in ('US','UK')
group by person_id
having   max(t_country.name) = 'UK'
```

Comment: Tthis is probably the best improvement if the index are setup properly.

Comment: @David Aldridge: Your second solution above was perfect.  Much, much faster.  Thank you.  Although doesn't your version depend on the string values between US and UK?

Comment: @Ask613 -- yes it does indeed, and it's really quite a special case where a very specific query can be optimised in a way that does not necessarily extend to other similar cases. If you wanted to test for "has visited FR and UK but not US or CA" then you'd probably be back to the EXISTS-based version. It is possible that that one might be further optimised by getting the relevant country_ids in a common table expression and using those in the correlated subqueries, to avoid the joins.

Comment: @DavidAldridge not necessarily. `having sum(case when t_country.name in ('FR','UK') then 1 end ) = 2 and sum(case when t_country.name in ('US','CA') then 1 end ) = 0 `  should do the trick

Comment: @Aツ yes, similar principle. How about ... visited UK, US and FR, or (CA and neither DE or MO)? Nah, just joking. You can generally construct all of these things with aggregates, but each one takes a bit of thought. I guess that's true with the exists method also, but that feels like it may be easier to construct for many cases.

Comment: @DavidAldridge :)  `having sum(case when t_country.name in ('US','FR','UK') then 1 end ) = 3 or sum(case when t_country.name in ('CA') then 1 when t_country.name in ('DE','MO') then -1 end ) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run analyze and execute this query?

```
-- females who visited UK
with uk_person as (
  select distinct person_id
  from t_last_city_visited t
  inner join t_person p on t.person_id = p.id and 'F' = p.gender
  where country_id  = (select id from t_country where name = 'UK')
),
-- females who visited US
us_person as (
  select distinct person_id
  from t_last_city_visited t
  inner join t_person p on t.person_id = p.id and 'F' = p.gender
  where country_id  = (select id from t_country where name = 'US')
)
-- females who visited UK but not US
select uk.person_id
from uk_person uk
left join us_person us on uk.person_id = us.person_id
where us.person_id is null
```

This is one of the many ways this query can be formed. You might have to run them to find out which one works best and indexing tweaks you may need to make to have them run faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would approach it, you can later substitute the inner queries by a with alias as @zedfoxus said

```
select 
    id 
from 
    (SELECT
        p.id id
    FROM
        t_person p JOIN t_last_city_visited lcv
            ON(lcv.person_id = p.id)
        JOIN country c
            ON(lcv.country_id = c.id  and cname = 'UK')
    WHERE
        p.gender = 'female') v JOIN

    (SELECT
        p2.id id
    FROM
        t_person p2 JOIN t_last_city_visited lcv2
            ON(lcv2.person_id = p2.id)
        JOIN country c
            ON(lcv.country_id = c.id  and cname != 'USA')
    WHERE
        p.gender = 'female') nv

        ON(v.id = nv.id)
```